# React app - render a feed in the background

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was looking to build a feed into a react app that as you were scrolling through it it will constantly fetch more data to display to you (it basically has no end). I was looking for a way to avoid re-rendering the whole  feed every time new data was fetched to be displayed to the user since it will start to get slow to re-render the whole component after a while.

I know I can do it with server-side rendering or through `ReactDom.createPortal` to render the element outside the react tree. The first option is out since that would be the only thing I would need a backend for and is not worth it.

The second option looks like the way to go but I am not sure if I can still access the state object and other react features from within the component rendered outside the react tree (I don't know if I would really need them or not but having them can't be bad)

Outside those two options, is there any other that I am not aware of?

Comment: Sorry but it's really unclear what you're asking...

Comment: Ok...my bad. To keep it short,I need a method to insert new content into a react component without re-rendering the whole thing

Comment: did u try polling ?

Comment: I am pretty much new to developing. What do you mean by polling?